# Bayesian linear regression: How to enforce constraint on the sum of coefficients?

Tags: regression, bayesian, prior, constrained-regression, brms

I have a linear regression problem in which my $X$ matrix is not full rank. Here is a small example:

$$X = 
\left[\begin{array}{rrrr}
-1 & 0 & 0 & 1 \\
1 & 0 & -1 & 0 \\
0 & 1 & -1 & 0 \\
0 & 0 & 1 & -1 \\
-1 & 0 & 1 & 0 \\
0 & 0 & -1 & 1 \\
1 & 0 & 0 & -1
\end{array}\right]
$$

As you can see, each row sum is equal to 0, thus $\mathbb{1}$ is in the nullspace of $X$, indicating the matrix is not full rank. I would like to "fix" this problem by enforcing the constraint that the sum of all 4 coefficients is equal to 0, thus guaranteeing a unique solution. I can do this in a frequentist OLS pretty easily, by using the technique described [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58441299/r-force-regression-coefficients-to-add-up-to-1) to get a new matrix $X'$, with one fewer dimension, and then proceed with the normal equations.

$$X' = 
\left[\begin{array}{rrr}
-2 & -1 & -1 \\
1 & 0 & -1 \\
0 & 1 & -1 \\
1 & 1 & 2 \\
-1 & 0 & 1 \\
-1 & -1 & -2 \\
2 & 1 & 1
\end{array}\right]
$$

However, I want to use a Bayesian approach by placing weakly informative priors around each of the coefficients. These priors are normal distributions that are **not** zero-centered. I should note I have priors that all 4 coefficients, including the coefficient for the dropped column.

My problem is that when I do Bayesian regression with these priors on the $X'$ dataset, the resulting posterior distribution for the 4th "hidden" coefficient is very wide and becomes almost nonsensical. I suspect this is because most default Bayesian software (I am using `brms` in R, which calls to Stan) assumes the priors are independent, when that is obviously not the case in my scenario (there has to be some negative correlation). Thus when I sample from the posteriors for the three coefficients, and use those to derive samples for the "hidden" coefficient (by taking the sum and multiplying by -1, as the coefficients must sum to 0), the posterior distribution is very wide, and many, many data points are required to get a tighter distribution that is about as wide as that for the other coefficients.

This is a problem because there is nothing "special" about the column that is dropped, yet the posterior for its coefficient will be a lot wider than that for the columns that are directly modeled.

How to resolve this?

One idea that I had is that I should somehow specify the prior as the entire joint distribution, but I'm not sure how to do this in `brms` or other software. I did some quick research on using covariance matrices with Bayesian approach, but I am not interested in estimating the matrix itself (placing a prior around it, etc.), moreso just relaxing the starting assumption that the priors are independent.

I should also note that in my full setting (~5000 data points, ~700 columns), the joint posterior clearly does have the required correlation between the coefficients, and the derived samples for the "hidden" coefficient are sensible. This issue only occurs when I have relatively few data points.

I found [this](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/120162/how-to-specify-a-hierarchical-bayesian-model-with-sum-to-zero-constraints) question which pretty much describes the same setting that I have, but it does not address my specific question.

Comment: You can adapt the procedure you linked for "frequentist" OLS: do MCMC with the exact same transformed matrix, and then apply the back-transformation to each posterior draw.

Comment: That's exactly what I did, my problem is that the posterior for the back-transformed coefficient is far more spread out than it "should" be (i.e., compared to the posteriors for the other coefficients, when really the posterior variances should be roughly the same)

Comment: OK, I figured out how to pass a multivariate normal as a full joint prior, but a) the time to sample from the posterior exploded; and b) it didn't *fully* rectify my issue (posterior was still wider than expected, but not as wide as it had been before)

Comment: oh yeah a) is cause you've got 700 cols and using the straightforward method would involve decomposing a 700x700 matrix on each iter. For b), I think we'd have to know more about the exact mvn you used. If you're using stan, here's another thing you can try: sample $\beta$ independently, per usual. Then define a new vector $\tilde{\beta}$ whose entry $\tilde{\beta}_i = \beta_i - \texttt{mean}(\beta)$. Now track $\tilde{\beta}$ instead of $\beta$ and use $\tilde{\beta}$ in the likelihood.

Comment: Alternatively, the stan page on intrinsic CARs (https://mc-stan.org/users/documentation/case-studies/icar_stan.html) talks about sum zero constraints in a slightly different setting (the prior is a correlated spatial prior). They seem to "solve" the problem by specifying:   // soft sum-to-zero constraint on phi
  sum(phi) ~ normal(0, 0.001 * N); // equivalent to mean(phi) ~ normal(0,0.001) [phi is their beta]

Comment: Thanks for the helpful comments. I am using Stan as a backend, but only via brms (which calls to rstan, and rstan calls to Stan). I think my issue is that the covariance matrix is not properly specified (and I am working through figuring out what it *should* be). Interesting about the soft constraint, I did not know that Stan could implement priors on the sum of coefficients (nor that this was a technique used often enough that it would be included in software)

Comment: It may be possible to hack this. Unfortunately, if we are going to use a covariance matrix which exactly enforces this constraint, it is going to be singular. This is not a problem if we were doing our own MCMC, but I suspect stan would not accept this. Thus, you should consider prior covariance matrices of this form: $\Omega = \frac{1}{\phi}\big((1+\epsilon)\mathbf{I}-\frac{1}{P}\mathbf{J}\big)$. The two hyperparameters in this expression are 1) $\phi$, a prior precision per usual 2) $\epsilon$ a "fudge factor" which you should set a small number (like 1e-6) and will have to tune.

Comment: ($\mathbf{I}$ is the $P\times P$ identity matrix and $\mathbf{J}$ is a matrix with all entries given as 1 (such that $\frac{1}{P}\mathbf{J}$ is a matrix filled with all $\frac{1}{P}$), and $P$ is the number of columns in your matrix (so about 700)). and please note this is a prior COVARIANCE matrix; stan maybe wants a precision? Not sure but double check. Exact enforcement of our constraint would amount to $\epsilon=0$, but this will lead to a singular covariance and stan will be unhappy.

Comment: My idea was to have a $(P - 1) \times (P - 1)$ covariance matrix (so 3x3 for the dummy example), such that the variance of the sum of the $P - 1$ coefficients equals my desired variance for the last coefficient. I have other uncertainties/correlations I want to include in my prior as well, but the structure you describe will be the bulk of it. Thanks!

Comment: I think that makes sense; in the $P-1\times P-1$ basis my suggestion looks like $\phi(\mathbf{I}-\frac{1}{P-1}\mathbf{J})$ where matrices are of size $P-1$ and you no longer need a nonzero $\epsilon$. Not that you asked, but if I were doing this, I would first get the sum zero constraint to work independently before attempting to impose my other "uncertainties/correlations".

Comment: Yes, this worked, I will draft up an answer now (including brms implementation)

Answer (score 3):

As I hinted at in the question, and as @John Madden explicitly laid out, it is possible to create a covariance matrix and define the entire joint prior distribution as a multivariate normal. In this setting, the correlation matrix has 1 on the diagonal, and $\frac{-1}{P-1}$ for every other element, where $P$ is the original number of features ($P = 4$, in the example from the question).

If all prior variances are equal, it can be shown that with this correlation matrix, the variance of the sum of all elements is equal to the variance of each individual element.

The other part of my question required implementation, ideally using `brms` in R. Here is a possible implementation, where `p` is as defined above, `priorMean` is a vector of length $P-1$ containing the prior means, and `priorVar` is a vector of length $P-1$ containing the prior variances (in my case, they were all roughly equal, but slightly different):

```
priorCor = matrix(-1/(p-1), nrow = p - 1, ncol = p - 1)
diag(priorCor) = 1
priorVcov = diag(priorVar ^ .5) %*% priorCor %*% diag(priorVar ^ .5)

model = brm(...,
  prior = set_prior("multi_normal(priorMean, priorVcov)"),
  stanvars = stanvar(priorMean) + stanvar(priorVcov)
  ...
)
```

where `...` represents other arguments to `brm` (formula, data, chains, cores, etc.)

Unfortunately, this solution can drastically increase sampling time. Originally, with independent priors and ~700 columns, the model took about 10 seconds to generate 1750 samples (500 warmup, 1250 saved), on a subset of 250 data points. On the full sample of ~5000 data points, it took about 45 minutes. After defining the prior as a (correlated) multivariate normal distribution, to generate the same number of samples, the small dataset took about 45 minutes, and the full dataset took close to 3 hours.

Comment: shame it takes so long in this software. because your covar is diagonal plus low rank, a lightning-fast custom implementation could be written.

Comment: What is interesting is that if a specify a covariance matrix that is diagonal (all off-diagonal is zero), the sampling still takes a very long time compared to specifying the same prior as a bunch of separate independent normals. But that is discussion for a different question. Thanks for your help!

Comment: presumably it is simply blindly performing "dense" matrix decompositions

Comment: oh now that I think of it there's a way to speed it up by taking the matrix decomposition ourselves and doing independent priors in the eigenbasis of the matrix if speed is important.

Comment: Thanks. I see the same behavior when I set `sample_prior="only"` in the brm call. Meaning just sampling from the multivariate normal itself is hard. But what is also weird is that I have another dataset with similar construction but only 350 columns (so half the size), and it only takes Stan a couple minutes to get that many samples just from the prior (compared to like an hour). I will post on Stan forums about this

Comment: matrix decomposition is cubic in matrix size, so we expect an algorithm dominated by matrix decomposition to take 8 times as long when input size is doubled. So the 350 column dataset would be expected to take around 7 minutes on the basis of a one hour run for the 700 col dataset.

Comment: It's more like 2 -> 60. Maybe that is within reasonable error bounds/"fudge factor" for cubic, but even something like 2 ->16 (actually cubic) would be acceptable.

Comment: what exact is the ~700? And what is the difference in the number of rows?

Comment: It is 363 and 726. So an exact 50%.  The number of rows in the larger dataframe is also 2x (so number of cells is 4x), but these timings I refer to are when I just sample from the prior, so the number of rows shouldn't make any difference (just the number of columns).

Comment: OK yes everything checks out that sounds indeed like a bigger discrepancy than would be expected.

Comment: https://discourse.mc-stan.org/t/issues-sampling-from-multivariate-normal-prior/33930